# MySQL query can't handle variables

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-7

I'm trying to query to my database, but for some reason the query is only working when I enter the parameters hard coded. If I use variables, the query refuses to work...

This is my query with hard coded parameters and works just fine:

```
$q_jobs = 'select distinct nid from node n, field_data_field_job_tags as tags
          where (type= \'job\' and n.language = \'nl\' and tags.entity_id = n.nid 
               and tags.field_job_tags_value = \'Enterprise Asset Management\') 
          order by n.changed desc limit 7';
```

But when I use variables, the query refuses to work...

```
 $q_jobs = 'select distinct nid from node n, field_data_field_job_tags as tags
              where (type= \'job\' and n.language = :lang and tags.entity_id = n.nid 
                   and tags.field_job_tags_value = :title) 
              order by n.changed desc limit 7';
 $results_jobs = db_query($q_jobs, array(':lang' => $language->language, 
                                         ':title' => $node->title));
```

Although it's a Drupal query, I assume it's just an error somewhere in my syntax?

I get this error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error 
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for
>   the right syntax to use near '(type= 'job' and n.language = 'nl' and tags.entity_id = 
>   n.nid and tags.field_job' at line 1: select distinct nid from {node} n, 
>   field_data_field_job_tags as tagswhere (type= 'job' and n.language = :lang and 
>   tags.entity_id = n.nid and tags.field_job_tags_value = :title)order by
>   n.changed desc limit 7; Array ( [:lang] => nl [:title] => Enterprise
>   Asset Management ) in rd_get_related_news_and_blogs()

Comment: Do you get any sort of error?

Comment: Yes, I'll add it to my question

Comment: type belongs to which table? all other field names are given as tablename.filed names in where caluse

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo here: `field_data_field_job_tags as tagswhere (type=` - there should be a space between `tags` and `where` so the quoted part of Your SQL should be `field_data_field_job_tags as tags where (type=`.

Always read all of the mysql error message - the query it is failing with is always quoted thus You can easily find any typo or other mistake in Your query.

EDIT: cos You don't believe me, here is repeated query from the mysql error message:

```
select distinct nid from {node} n, field_data_field_job_tags as tagswhere (type= 'job' and n.language = :lang and tags.entity_id = n.nid and tags.field_job_tags_value = :title)order by n.changed desc limit 7;
```

Now see where You have a `newline` in Your query and where should be (and is not) a space within the query MySQL returned as failing.
Then put a space at the end of every line and see that the query is working...

I will help You, there should be space between `tags` and `where` and between `\'Enterprise Asset Management\')` and `order by` - but it is NOT. The only space is between `n.nid` and `and tags.field_job_tags_value` because of the tab space...

Comment: There is a newline separating the two. It's considered a space too.

Comment: @Truth if it would be considered as a space why then the query in the mysql error message would say `field_data_field_job_tags as tagswhere (type=`???

Comment: Because that's how the error is formatted when viewed in HTML. If the error were to be viewed as source, you'd see the line break.